# Asynctask receive data from server

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

hi guys im new in android programming and  need some help in asynctask , i can already send data but i dont know how to receive  a message from the server.

so far this is my code:

```
 public void getIpandPort()
    {
        String iPandPort = txtAddress.getText().toString();
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP String:" + iPandPort);
        String temp[] = iPandPort.split(":");
        wifiModuleIp = temp[0];
        wifiModulePort = Integer.valueOf(temp[1]);
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP:" + wifiModuleIp);
        Log.d("MY TEST ","PORT:" + wifiModulePort);

    }

    public  class Socket_AsyncTask extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {    
        Socket socket;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.wifiModuleIp);
                socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(CMD);
                dataOutputStream.close();    
                socket.close();
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();}catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have internet permissions ?

Comment: Yes sir i already set and i can send data

Comment: You would need to open a socket on your phone. Same as you did on the server... However, a phones address is not consistent across networks, so why do you need this?

Comment: i need to recieve a message from my server when i click a button my textview will be updated, the code above can only send data to server

Comment: Does it have to be a socket connection, or can you do it with a HTTP request?  Android has good tools for the latter.